# Sending action from Javascript/PHP hosted on localhost to a WPF application

Tags: javascript, c#, php, wpf

I managed to send data from my wpf application to my web server using the HttpWebRequest class.
Now I want to do the same thing but in the other direction. From my web application, I perform actions that must call a class from my wpf app to each action.

1. I first try to set up a system on my wpf application to receive requests send from PHP but nothing to do
2. The second solution would be to create an action table in my MySQL database (being the only thing in common between the two applications). In this case my wpf application should go continuously check if a new line is created in this table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple ways of how to handle inter-process communication. For PHP you can use of the following:

- [named pipes](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.posix-mkfifo.php)
- [sockets](https://www.php.net/sockets)
- [streams](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.stream.php)

For c# you can use

- [WCF](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/whats-wcf)
- [Sockets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.socket?view=netframework-4.8)

just to name few. Each having its advantages and drawbacks. The database connection is also possible but I would not encourage using it as there are plenty of ways mentioned above that are created just for this purpose.

Comment: So I have to create on c# side, a "socket" in my WPF application or a new project related to my application to consume with PHP?

Comment: Yes, you can think of it as an embedded server in your WPF application that listens for incoming connections. Then you can send requests from your PHP application. Depending on the application needs you have to choose the protocol and message format.